# Python 3.9 check if input is INT or FLOAT

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am gradually learning Python, using version 3.9.

I want to check if an input() is an INT or FLOAT, i have the following script but whatever i enter the first IF always runs.

```
i = input("Please enter a value: ")


if not isinstance(i, int) or not isinstance(i, float):
    print("THis is NOT an Integer or FLOAT")

elif isinstance(i, int) or isinstance(i, float):
    print("THis is an Integer or FLOAT")
```

could someone explain what i am doing wrong please

Comment: `i` is always string.

Comment: `input()` always returns a string, which is neither an int nor a float. Even if it were an int or a float, you'd always go into the first `if` because `x or y` is true if either `x` or `y` are true.

Comment: so is there a way i can check if input value is either an INT or FLOAT ??

EG like a TryConvert ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check with something like this. Get the input and covert it to float if it raises value error then it's not `float/int`. then use [`is_integer()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#float.is_integer) method of `float` to determine whether it's int or float

Test cases

```
-22.0 -> INT
22.1 -> FLOAT
ab -> STRING
-22 -> INT
```

Code:

```
i = input("Please enter a value: ")       
try:
    if float(i).is_integer():
        print("integer")
    else:
        print("float")
except ValueError:
    print("not integer or float")
```

Comment: You covered why it is not working on comment so added the code explanation.

Comment: Note that the check does not correctly separate integer-valued float literals from integer literals (i.e. what Python itself would do). Compare ``float("1").is_integer()`` and ``float("1.0").is_integer()`` to ``type(1)`` and ``type(1.0)``.